# How to collect and store data from a wizard application?

Tags: asp.net, database-design, architecture, wizard

I'm designing a wizard application for a client. 
This is a typical wizard scenario where you have a Start/Welcome page, followed by several sections/categories (each on a separate page/view), then a Summary page and confirmation page.

My question is about how to store the information the user enters during the wizard process? 
If you consider each screen/view of the wizard as a category/section, with each having a set of questions/fields (radiobuttons, dropdowns, textboxes,...) that the user needs to answer/fill, would you have 1 database table for each of those screens/views and hence 1 column for each question/field??

Or is there a more effective way of collecting the data and storing it?

Comment: Why do you need a database? Can't you do it more simply with an object, an XML tree, a settings file or some other less structured way?

Answer (score 0):

you have couple ways.

one of them is - as you mentioned - database. I would create simple data model for this and store each data in seperate field

if it's web application and you don't need to restore users status you can use session and just keep there data

or you can - as Frazz wrote - use file and store it in some for that is easy to read and update like xml